# How can i handle retrofit errors or get url request for to detect problems

Tags: android, kotlin, error-handling, retrofit, android-jetpack

I am trying to learn develop android applications and I'm trying to implement the latest approaches. So i use as many jetpack libraries as possible. (Dagger-Hilt, Coroutines, Retrofit etc)

Here is my question:

i have AppModule object for dependency injection.

Here is my retrofit object:

```
@Singleton 
@Provides 
fun provideConverterApi(): ConverterAPI {
    return Retrofit.Builder()
        .baseUrl(Constants.BASE_URL)
        .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
        .build()
        .create(ConverterAPI::class.java)
}
```

How can i get error messages from there or for example i need to see the url i use for the request, how can i do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're doing great, to add a logger for your network call use this way:

```
.addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
.addInterceptor(HttpLoggingInterceptor().apply {
                level = if (DEBUG) BODY else NONE 
})
.build()
```

Answer (score 1):

Base on @Amjad Alwareh, remember to add the dependence of the HTTP logging interceptor.

```
implementation "com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:${okHttpVersion}", // 3.12.1 or other version
```

Maybe the `DEBUG` should be `BuildConfig.DEBUG`